# How to get latitude and longitude from google place map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know i am asking silly question for your type of knowledgeable coding expert but i am not...
I am working on map to get latitude and longitude (coordinates) of searched location or by dragging location marker but i am not getting success.
I think you can help me to improve.I searched for lot of example here and I got many references but it is not as per my requirement because it only search for location not deep till particular address as shown in my fiddle.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rmr7c9hv/2/)

```js
function initialize() {

    var markers = [];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
    map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable:true,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            markers.push(marker);

            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 16px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
    width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lat, Lng doesn't update when I drag marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480496/lat-lng-doesnt-update-when-i-drag-marker)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of a draggable marker in a map (using javascript) into a form in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156233/is-it-possible-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-marker-in-a-map)

Comment: if you know answer try to help me for my example because i have already used [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hq0b49/).but search box of this map doesn't give me proper search which i want.you can try.so now i am trying on this new example.@geocodezip

Comment: @geocodezip-Try to help me if you know answer b'coz i am new for this all.i tried [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hq0b49/) but it is not responding me for proper search.For conformation you can try.so i am working on new example.Thank you in advance if you can do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily update your existing Fiddle to implement this by adding the following code after the creation of the marker:

```
var latInput = document.getElementsByName('latitude')[0];
var lngInput = document.getElementsByName('longitude')[0];
latInput.value = place.geometry.location.lat()
lngInput.value = place.geometry.location.lng();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
    latInput.value = e.latLng.lat();
    lngInput.value = e.latLng.lng();
});
```

I've forked and updated your fiddle to reflect this addition:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCookDev/hwp13f8p/2/)

The additional code updates your latitude and longitude inputs after adding the last place marker.

You'll need to bear in mind that the [SearchBox class' getPlaces method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox) could return multiple entries (with different locations) and only the last place's latitude and longitude will be displayed by the additional code.

The additional code also adds a [marker dragend event handler](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) to update your location inputs after any added markers have been dragged to a new position.