# How to move google map marker and get current lat and lon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use google map to get current lat and lon of user:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCfbbmUkl56UuSeZ5nSOwsKTNxplmnheuU&callback=initialize&language=en" async defer></script>
```

the user should change the marker and I get new lat and lon.

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please read and apply the following instructions [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) ! If you improve your question, you improve your chances for us to help you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the latitude and longitude of a draggable marker in a map (using javascript) into a form in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156233/is-it-possible-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-marker-in-a-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lat, Lng doesn't update when I drag marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480496/lat-lng-doesnt-update-when-i-drag-marker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code snippet that automatically detect user location by Using HTML Geolocation method. Make sure your browser enable location when you run this application and provide proper google map API link and most impotent the API key. Here is link of [MDN Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) where you can find detailed about geolocation and browser support information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Click Me to show Your Location.</button>

    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>

    <script>
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myCenter,
                zoom: 5
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                map.setZoom(9);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Google Maps has several types of overlays, Ex - Marker, Polyline, Polygon, Info Windows & Custom overlays. If you want to change it's pretty simple. Go through this [W3School Link](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_overlays.asp) i think this will help you - @ S.M_Emamian